# JavaScript basics/instructional

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have just begun giving JavaScript a try on a programmer friend's suggestion (though I have used it to some extent before with websites using jQuery without fully understanding the intricacies of the language itself) and was wondering how certain features work.

**Question:**

What other uses of JavaScript are there aside from websites (by itself and/or with jQuery framework)? Is there a difference between making a site interactive and an actual "web app"? I've heard the term and don't know the difference.

To add to my main question:

I've read and done some tutorials on prototyping and am not sure on its actual application (since what little I've dabbled in, by making a website more interactive, I've never seen them used). Can someone link a website with extensive deep/heavy JavaScript use so I can check it out?

**Gist:**

In essence, what I'm trying to understand is where heavy use of JavaScript comes into play because so far, all JavaScript I've experienced is superficial.

Appreciate in advance any advice/help in this matter!

Comment: Javascript is the language of the browser and web.

Comment: You can also use JavaScript within Acrobat Adobe, Microsoft Office (13+), and it runs fine on most any OS. But unless you need [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with some actual code, probably not the right forum for this question...

Comment: whole frameworks have been developed in javascript to move a lot of traditional server tasks from server to browser ... read up on *single page applications* . A framework is different and more robust than a *library* like jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What other uses of Javascript are there aside from websites (by itself and/or with jQuery framework)?

Check out [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). It runs JavaScript programs not intended for web use. Node offers a bunch of imports for things like file system IO, socket IO and a bunch of others. I personally use it for a WebSocket server because I don't like my alternatives.

Further, JavaScript has native support in many operating systems, including all Windows versions after and including XP (not sure about before). Windows Script Host runs .js files as JScript and these can be used to achieve things like those node can. It's a convenient way to do things batch can't.